# Present Perfect Continuous "Has been she talking ?"

Tags: present-perfect

"Has been she talking on the phone ? " Is it correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Has she been talking?

Subject---> Verb is standard english format.

"Has" being the question word, she is the subject, and "Been talking" is past participle + gerund, The subject will always precede the verb.

Answer (score 0):

No.  "Has she been talking on the phone?" would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

In a yes/no question, the first item is the first word in the verb phrase.

Your verb phrase is 'has been talking'

Place the first word of this phrase, (has) first.
Next add your subject, (she).

Then simply finish the verb phrase followed by any other elements.
Look at this example of a very long verb phrase and notice where I place the first two items of the question.

Jake could have been sleeping.

Could Jake have been sleeping?
I hope that helps.